# Python facebook-sdk multiquery

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to make a multiquery using graph.fql but I can't get it to work and I don't see any examples in the documentation. I'm trying to run

```
'user_sex': 'SELECT sex FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
```

first and then

```
'friends': 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND NOT (sex IN #user_sex) ORDER BY name')
```

second, but I don't have any clue on how to do so.

Will I have to make two separate queries?

Answer (score 1):

The python `facebook-sdk` library can execute multiple FQL queries. You need to cast your dictionary of queries into a string first.

```
import facebook

query = {
    "user_sex": "SELECT sex FROM user WHERE uid=me()",
    "friends": "SELECT uid, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND not (sex in (select sex from #user_sex))  ORDER BY name"
}

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
return graph.fql(str(query))
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your queries a little. You can try it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%7B%0A%22user_sex%22%3A%20%22SELECT%20sex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme%28%29%22%2C%0A%22friends%22%3A%20%22SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20sex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%20AND%20not%20%28sex%20in%20%28select%20sex%20from%20%23user_sex%29%29%20%20ORDER%20BY%20name%22%0A%7D). Click "Get access token" if there are none.

```
{
"user_sex": "SELECT sex FROM user WHERE uid=me()",
"friends": "SELECT uid, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND not (sex in (select sex from #user_sex))  ORDER BY name"
}
```

Also you really don't have to make several queries. You can use this one ([test it](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid%2Cname%2C%20sex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%20order%20by%20name)):

```
SELECT uid,name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND not (sex in (SELECT sex FROM user WHERE uid=me())) order by name
```

To make a request from your app you should encode data properly. For example for both this queries urls would be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=%7B%22user_sex%22:%22SELECT%20sex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()%22,%22friends%22:%22SELECT%20uid,%20name,%20sex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me())%20AND%20not%20(sex%20in%20(select%20sex%20from%20%23user_sex))%20%20ORDER%20BY%20name%22%7D&access_token=token
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid,+name,+sex+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())+AND+not+(sex+in+(SELECT+sex+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=me()))+order+by+name&access_token=token
```

Comment: The first one works perfectly but do you know how I can make that fql query with the python facebook-sdk https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk